# How to include fontawesome in simple html5 and css 3 project

Tags: html, css

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZKeP.png)

Can anyone help me how to include fontawesome in the html5 and css 3 project?

Comment: close the link tag `>` and follow the documentation https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick a desired version and pack at their [Start page](https://fontawesome.com/start) and include a  tag into  section of your page, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Other ways of installing it listed on same page.

Here is a working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


<span style="font-size: 3em; color: Tomato;">
  <i class="fas fa-igloo"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: I have tried with this approach by linking in my index.html.But still not able to access the font awesome.

Comment: @BikashMohapatra I added a snippet with working example, you can run it and ensure that this approach is 100% working.